# Android: override Google Maps v2 maximum zoom

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm developing an app which needs maximum zoom set to level way past upper limit in Google Maps V2 (for an indoor navigation). I'm looking for a level 22, 23 or even 24. 

Two solutions came into my mind:

1. Max zoom limit in Google Maps can be overwritten.
2. Use translation and render one small tile into a big square build from nine tiles or more. Tile quality is not an issue for me.

Are any of these ways possible? Or maybe there is another map engine, that supports zooming past level 21? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(value)`, but I didn't try.

Answer (score -1):

You can use inbuilt method,

```
googleMap.getMaxZoomLevel()
```

Using above method you will get maximum zoom level, you don't need to set it manually.

Comment: I don't need to get maximum zoom level, I need to move past maximum.

Comment: Thanks for `getMaxZoomLevel()`. Currently it is 21.